# Line after first row and column in HTML table

Tags: html

How can one distinguish first row and left-most column in HTML table. Preferably with a line separating these from the rest columns/rows.

I found few partial solutions, but they all refer to updating CSS. Since I want to include this table in a wordpress blog (I think that) I don't have access to head and thus cannot include CSS style, neither there is an option to include any JavaScript script.

Table:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>  <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1<td>  </td><td>0.2</td><td>1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>  <td>0.5</td><td></td><td>-0.7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>  <td>0.3</td><td>0.9</td><td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Expected outcome:

[image]

Comment: So you want to edit the style of the table without changing the CSS?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine. As you can see I'm not able to translate all CSS into pure HTML myself.

Comment: @DawidL. Who says that you cannot add the CSS and Javascript? You can edit the body and use the inline CSS. For javascript you can include `<script>...</script>` Tag. Try it.

Comment: @JafferWilson wordpress.com says so. I've just tried these styles and scripts and it doesn't work.

Comment: @DawidL. Are you trying to display it like a matrix and want to high light the x and y values displayed in first row and first column?

Comment: Something like this: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/two-headers/#table-with-header-cells-in-the-top-row-and-first-column

Comment: @JafferWilson This is closer, but not exactly the same. I understand that they use table headers, but I still want to separate them with a line from the all blocks. Please see updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall use:

- for left column `n-th child` selector

  td:nth-child(n) {
    /* your stuff here */
  }
- for first row `th` tag

**Example:**

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 100%">
  <tr style="border-bottom: 3px solid #000;background-color: #d3d3d3 !important;">
    <th  style="background-color: #d3d3d3 !important;border-right: 3px solid #000;padding: 8px;"></th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #d3d3d3 !important;border-right: 3px solid #000;padding: 8px;">1</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>0.2</td>
    <td>1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color: #f5f5f5">
    <td style="background-color: #d3d3d3 !important;border-right: 3px solid #000;padding: 8px;">2</td>
    <td>0.5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>-0.7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #d3d3d3 !important;border-right: 3px solid #000;padding: 8px;">3</td>
    <td>0.3</td>
    <td>0.9</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok. But how to use that?

Comment: @Arttem Solvev Still nothing. Where do I include this? I cannot add any CSS, nor JS. Table is eventually going to wordpress.com, which is quite limited.

Comment: This is pretty close! I wasn't aware that you can simply put style as a attribute. One thing missing, though: line.

Comment: @DawidL. Line but not a header? Or even lines?

Comment: @DawidLaszuk Check the snippet

Comment: Great! Snippet is what I wanted.